# INTERSECT 2 data in case null oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have a case that want support.
I have data1 and data2.

If data2 have data => expect: data1 INTERSECT  data2.

If data2 no data => expect: data1

So, how to make it with simple sql in oracle.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question

Comment: To the upvoter: why?

Comment: When `data2` has no data, do you want everything in `data1` **including duplicates**, or do you want `data1` to be de-duplicated just as it is when you do `INTERSECT`?

Comment: I want to return data1, it can duplicates or no

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
select * from data1 where not exists (select * from data2)
union all
(select * from data1 intersect select * from data2)
;
```

Comment: Thank for your sharing. It is OK